# 3rd Level Dot Notation With Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm rather new to Angular and I am losing my mind trying to find information on how to access the third level of a controller.  Below you'll see a simplified version of my code.  I would expect the expression to resolve as "2".  Instead, it produces nothing.

My code is working fine otherwise.  For instance, when I, instead, use thisDatasheet.settings, the page renders the array as expected... I just can't access that grand-child level.

Oddly, elsewhere in my code, when I have inner loops, I am able to access the 3rd level by referencing the parent loop.  Is there some kind of wrapping I need to do?  I would hate to have to wrap this in an outer loop for no reason... that seems a little messy to me.

I'm sure there's some fundamental practice which I'm missing here that hasn't been covered in any of the online tutorials I have done.

Thanks in advance!

```js
{"datasheets":[
  {
    "title":"Thing 1",
    "settings":[
      {
        "topdisplay":"columns",
        "bottomcolumns":"2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title":"Thing 2",
    "settings":[
      {
        "topdisplay":"stacked",
        "bottomcolumns":"2"
      }
    ]
  }
]}
```

```html
<div data-ng-repeat="thisDatasheet in datasheets">
  <div class="columns-{{thisDatasheet.settings.bottomcolumns}}">
    My content goes here!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `settings` is also an array, so you would either have to iterate over that or just access the `[0]`th element since it seems like there is always only 1

Comment: Totally unrelated, but wouldn't `thisDatasheet` be better expressed as simply `datasheet`, or even just `sheet`?

Comment: Settings appears to be an array with an object in it. try: `thisDatasheet.settings[0].bottomcolumns`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try accessing the [0] element of the thisDatasheet.settings array object.

```
thisDatasheet.settings[0].bottomcolumns
```

Or, try making settings a regular object:

```
{"datasheets":[
  {
    "title":"Thing 1",
    "settings":
      {
        "topdisplay":"columns",
        "bottomcolumns":"2"
      }
  },
  {
    "title":"Thing 2",
    "settings":
      {
        "topdisplay":"stacked",
        "bottomcolumns":"2"
      }
  }
]}
```

If you only plan on having one set of settings per sheet.

Comment: AHA! Yes, of course, just referencing with a third dot notation wouldn't work because the SECOND level is an array, too, even though there is only one item in it! I should have realized that! Yes, this will certainly work since I do only plan on having one "settings" group per main record. Awesome! Thank you!